# Restsharp - parse multipartformdata reponse

Tags: c#, multipartform-data, restsharp

I'm using Restsharp to POST a JSon body, the response is multipart/mixed. Is there a built-in way in RestSharp to parse this data? (I'm processing Colissimmo shipping label responses)
In Postman the header shows this:

Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary="uuid:732122b7-58d5-4122-a4c1-333425d88699";charset=UTF-8

The content of the response is similar to this. I would like to have the Json info and the ZPL label in separate objects. What would be the easiest way?

this is the response:

```
--uuid:732122b7-58d5-4122-a4c1-333425d88699
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <jsonInfos>

{"messages":[{"id":"0","type":"INFOS","messageContent":"La requête a été traitée avec succès","replacementValues":[]}],"labelXmlV2Reponse":null,"labelV2Response":{"parcelNumber":"6C15123444991","parcelNumberPartner":"0075007XXXXX79254499802250R","pdfUrl":null,"fields":{"field":[{"key":"NETWORK_NAME","value":""},{"key":"PARTNER_NAME","value":""},{"key":"PARTNER_CAB","value":""},{"key":"CN23_THERMIQUE","value":""}],"customField":[{"key":"NETWORK_NAME","value":""},{"key":"PARTNER_NAME","value":""},{"key":"PARTNER_CAB","value":""},{"key":"CN23_THERMIQUE","value":""}]}}}
--uuid:732122b7-58d5-4122-a4c1-333425d88699
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <label>

﻿CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA
^PW1181
^LS0000
^LT0000
^FO1056,0^GFA,06656,06656,00016,:Z64:
eJztl02SpCAQhSFcuOQIHIW+GXbMYq7FUTiCSxeEtAIi+fCnLbuqZyIqd190F+bLl5kiY+/436PxU4wrtzP7fRbw/zLyx8JqZsfswjow7wkPK4fj+2bYYR7Yto6yWDik740Ydzim3ym/wyLK074r5MxsCjnjlFXJbmJb8MAz64V7IqfmgcgDFvMzSjnAcrEgycksFnnJsizHR4HIWV4SmOUlTu6FpIi8xFlOEgjM4ykhyyFwl7McgpyVXeA16y3mRdYF6/V8k7MIBQ1ZxiKt+fmV9cp2i9XKZovlyt0WRz/6+djCH6sWv6KfVtbsNvsB+yUVHHntt1gaXrONnEqZ+zsIGCvWhIt5SesB...
```

Comment: No, RestSharp doesn't support parsing multipart forms in responses.